# Any open source Rails apps for managing employee's times?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, open-source, time

I've seen things in PHP for this like [TimeClock](http://timeclock.sourceforge.net/) . Its an app that manages Vacations / Hours / etc.

Anyone know of a Rails equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you're looking for is a rails timesheet. you can check [these](http://www.opensourcerails.com/projects?tag=timesheet) out